# componentWillMount fails to set the state

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component called Home.js which retrieves the data from an API and send the data as a property to it's child component DishItem.js that shows the dish details. I am trying to render the dish_name, quantity (that can be changed) and net_cost, and I am storing all of these in a state and setting their state for the initial render through componentWillMount() lifecycle method. But it fails to set the state and returns undefined.

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DishItem from './DishItem';
import $ from 'jquery';

export default class Home extends Component {
 constructor() {
 super();
 this.state = {
   dish: ''
  }
}

getDishes() {
 $.ajax({
   url: 'http://testbed2.riktamtech.com/foody_buddy/public/api/dishes/dish/31816',
   dataType: 'json',
   cache: false,
   success: function(response) {
     this.setState({dish: response.data});
  }.bind(this),
  error: function(xhr, status, err) {
    console.log(err);
    }
  });
 }

componentWillMount() {
 this.getDishes();
}

componentDidMount() {
 this.getDishes();
}

render() {
 return (
   <div className="Home">
     <DishItem dish={this.state.dish}/>
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

**DishItem.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import Quantity from './Quantity';
    import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
    import './style.css';

    export default class DishItem extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          quantity: 1,
          delivery: '',
          total_cost: '',
          net_cost: null,
          counter: 1
        }
      }

      componentWillMount() {
        console.log(this.props.dish.net_cost); //undefined instead of some value
        this.setState({net_cost: this.props.dish.net_cost}); 
        console.log(this.state.net_cost); // null
      }

      handleChangeInQuantity(value) {
        var net_cost = 0;
        var total_cost = 0;
        total_cost = value * this.props.dish.cost;
        net_cost = value * this.props.dish.net_cost;
        this.setState({quantity: value, net_cost: net_cost, total_cost: total_cost});
      }

      saveAndContinue(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }

      render() {
        let address = <div>{this.props.dish.address}<br/>{this.props.dish.landmark}<br/>{this.props.dish.locality}</div>
        return (
          <div>
            <h3>{this.props.dish.name}<small>{this.props.dish.description}</small></h3>
            Total- {this.state.net_cost}

            <Quantity change_in_quantity={this.handleChangeInQuantity.bind(this)} />
            <button className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.saveAndContinue.bind(this)}>Next</button>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Are you rendering the component on the backend or the front end?

Comment: i am rendering it on the front-end,when i am logging the output through i am getting the states values as undefined

Answer (score 2):

componentWillMount() function is triggered only once, it does not wait to get the data from the server. you should use componentWillReceiveProps() in the DishItem component, and set the new state with the data sent from the Home component to it. This way whenever the DishItem receives new props from the Home component, it will update accordingly.

Comment: I have to disagree, the correct place to load the data asynchronously would be in the componentdidmount method of the home component. See life cycle documentation, where it says so: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount

Comment: indeed, however that is in the Home component, or the parent component in this case. in the DishItem component, or the child component, you need to use componentWillReceiveProps() in order to update the state. updating the state in componentWillMount() will not get the new data since it is still not fetched from the server.

Comment: No, when he loads the data in Home.componentDidMount, React will render the Home component twice, once on initial render without the data in the state, then again when the asynchronous data loading is done and the state of the component is updated. Which is the typical way of handling such a use case.

Comment: I am not saying fetching the data at componentDidMount is wrong. What I am saying is that in the child component, the only trigger that happens when the parent component changes state is the componentWillReceiveProps, since it's receiving the new state as props. so that is where the state should be updated, and not in DishItem.componentWillMount. @PatrickHund

Comment: @MamdohSaraireh But how do i render the dish cost initially?

Comment: @ChaitanyaSairam try a blocking ajax call async : false

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the `componentWillMount` method of a React component to do asynchronous data fetching. Remove your call to the `getDishes` method and leave it in `componentDidMount`. In the `render` method of your Home component, check if the state already has the dish data in the state. If it doesn't, don't render the DishItem component. You can put a "Please wait, loading" message or something like that instead.

When the page is loaded, React will render the component with the "loading " message and start loading the dish data asynchronously. When the data is done loading and the state is set, React will render the component again with the DishItem component.

Here's an updated version of your Home component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DishItem from './DishItem';
import $ from 'jquery';

export default class Home extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            dish: null
        };
    }

    getDishes() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://testbed2.riktamtech.com/foody_buddy/public/api/dishes/dish/31816',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                this.setState({ dish: response.data });
            }.bind(this),
            error(xhr, status, err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getDishes();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Home">
                {
                    this.state.dish === null ?
                        <div>Please wait, loading…</div> :
                        <DishItem dish={this.state.dish} />
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't answer my question, how do i render the cost of the dish in the initial render?

Comment: Your DishItem will only be rendered after the data has been loaded (before, it will just be the “please wait” message, so your dish prop will contain the data you need when it is finally rendered.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that I can't add a comment so I will just send this since there are already many answers. Please don't give me minus one because of this :)

Even though it is in componentDidMount, once it fetches the data, it will re-render the DOM so it will look like it is the initial render. If the fetching is slow, you will see it blank for a moment and then renders to what you need it to be.

If you really really need to make it show up at the very first moment, I suggest that you fetch the data and save it inside Flux store or Redux store before redirecting to this page. For example, fetch the data and do the redirection inside then() or callback function.

Comment: really bro? I need 50 to make a comment where I only have 22 since I don't usually have time to answer questions. I physically can't make a comment man. Fine, I suppose I shouldn't have helped in the first place.